# how to get rid of warning -- NOTE: Invalid numeric data, secdiags='V146'

Tags: sas, warnings

I have written the following code  that runs with warnings like

```
NOTE: Invalid numeric data, secdiags='V4975' , at line 68 column 6.
NOTE: Invalid numeric data, secdiags='V4589' , at line 68 column 6.
NOTE: Invalid numeric data, secdiags='V146' , at line 68 column 6"
```

Due to these warnings, records with these values are getting dropped off from the final output.
What should I do to keep these values in?

Diag1, diag2, diag3...diagN columns are char columns with values like
V4965
V4966
V4967
V520
3536
9059
99760
99761
99762

```
 Data work.temp1 ;
  set work.nocabg;   

 array secdiaggg {*} diag: ; 
 array diag{*} diag:;     


LENGTH j 3.;
j = 1;       
/* put diag1= diag2 = diag3= diag[n]= into 1 code per line.*/
do until ( j > dim(secdiaggg)); 
    secdiags = diag[j];   /* Creates new CHAR column name secdiags */
    j = j + 1;
    IF secdiags NE . THEN OUTPUT;;  /* This put each Diag code on a separate line for the patient. */
end;
```

drop j; 
run;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you have two arrays of the same variables (`secdiaggg` and `diag`), but you presumably are running into an issue with this line:

```
IF secdiags NE . THEN OUTPUT;;
```

`.` is numeric missing.  `secdiags` is character.  So you want

```
IF secdiags NE ' ' THEN OUTPUT;
```

Or, better:

```
if not missing(secdiags) then output;
```

as the `missing` function tests both equally.

Comment: Also: it looks like you're doing a transpose, you might want to consider `proc transpose` as it's fairly good at that sort of thing.

Comment: IF secdiags NE ' ' THEN OUTPUT; helped solve the problem! Thanks a ton.  I am new to SAS and 1 week old in arrays.  I felt that secdiaggg and diag were the same but was afraid to change code that was working.  I am trying to merge several rows of records for the same ID into a single column of secdiags without having any values repeated.  Not sure if proc transpose will do it that.  Also I have to bring it back to the original table layout. where each records is for 1 ID and all secdiags in columns..but will study proc transpose.